# create a color effect around the edge of the video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm confused about how to write what I want.

but i can explain in beginner's way.

I want to create an effect like an image stroke that surrounds the corners of the video. for example starts at center corner then plays and ends at center corner again if duration is over.

how do i make it with ffmpeg ?